# Symfony Doctrine How do i find out where/when Lazy Relations are fetched

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I am working on an action which uses layered Relations. 
So i have a Player Entity, which has a Relation OwnedCard. Which has a Relation CardLevel which has a Relation card.
So i am using

```
/**
 * @param Player $player
 * @Route("/{id}/cards", name="loki.tuo.ownedcard.cards.show", requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 *
 * @ParamConverter("player", class="LokiTuoResultBundle:Player", options={"repository_method" = "findWithOwnedCards"})
 * @return Response
 * @Security("is_granted('view.player', player)")
 */
public function showCardsForPlayerAction(Player $player)
{
    $allCards = $player->getOwnedCards();
    $allCards = Collection::make($allCards)->sortBy(function (OwnedCard $elem) {
        //$elem->getCard() calls the getName() method on CardLevel which delegates it to Card
        return $elem->getCard()->getName();
    });
    $deck = $allCards->filter(function (OwnedCard $item) {
        return $item->getAmountInDeck() > 0;
    });
    $combined = $deck->map(function (OwnedCard $item) {
        return $item->toDeckString();
    });
    $formOptions = ['attr' => ['class' => 'data-remote']];
    $ownedCardForm = $this->createForm(OwnedCardType::class, null, $formOptions);

    $massOwnedCardForm = $this->createForm(MassOwnedCardType::class, null, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('loki.tuo.ownedcard.card.add.mass', ['id' => $player->getId()]),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ]);
    //Render Template
```

For this I created a method which Joins and Selects these Relations

```
public function findWithOwnedCards($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('player')
        ->join('player.ownedCards', 'ownedCards')
        ->join('ownedCards.card', 'cardLevel')
        ->join('cardLevel.card', 'card')
        ->addSelect(['ownedCards'])
        ->addSelect(['cardLevel'])
        ->addSelect(['card'])
        ->where('player.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
}
```

But Unfortunately the Symfony Profiler tells me, there are a lot calls like

```
SELECT * FROM card_level  WHERE card_id = ?
```

(I shortened the Query for better readability)
So this means, at some point Symfony/Doctrine doesnt use the Joined Relationships but somehow thinks they are lazy loaded, and needs to fetch them.

So now my Question: How can I find out, where or when the queries are executed? Is there some point in the Code where I could set a breakpoint or throw an Exception to see a stacktrace to see where this comes from?

Comment: Try using innerJoin instead of join. It should works I use it a lot

Comment: I don't know how  this could change anything. Inside the Debugger I _can see_ that the Data is fetched properly. But somehow still somewhere is some lazyloading

Comment: Is it possible there is just another query later in your code?

Comment: I Updated the Question so one can see the full Code of the Action. So I guess it is pretty clear there is no other Query

Comment: We do'nt see how you get the `$player`. It could also be calls in twig

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 'fetch' property to "EAGER" for your associations
Here's an example from doctrine docs
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone